# StageWebView - Change system browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Running StageWebView on a Windows Desktop machine, uses IE as it's browser, no matter what is the systems default Internet Browser. Is it possible to change this to Chrome?

I'm not interested in the built in Webkit browser in AIR

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the answer is no, the [StageWebView class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) on mobile or desktop uses the OS provided web control to display content on the Stage:

> On desktop computers (in the desktop and extended desktop profiles),
>   the [StageWebView class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) uses the system web control provided by the
>   Flash Player plugin.

Thus on Windows that would be Internet Explorer (IE) via the IWebBrowser2 interface which Google's Chrome does not support.

Note: This is assuming you are passing **true** for the useNative parameter on the  StageWebView constructor, otherwise the on Windows/OS-X you would get the old built-in Webkit version. This can be checked by seeing which user-agent is used (try http://whatsmyuseragent.com or similar to verify)

**Air 18 (or 19 beta results in same rendering) on Windows and OS-X:**

[image: IE11]

[image: SAFARI8]

Comment: When I'm using NativeMode (on windows desktop) some webpages dont display correctly...looks like no CSS.. This page doesn't display at all http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/icon.html However everything works fine directly on IE..!?

Comment: When you are creating the StageWebView object are you passing true for the useNative parameter? (I'm assuming not and you are getting the old Webkit version), see the API link in my answer for the constructor parameter : "StageWebView(useNative:Boolean = false)" Pass true and your web pages should work fine, assuming IE works on them...

Comment: I am that's my point, it's using IE, but it's not displaying the sites the same as if using IE directly.. Very strange.. I can't use it WebKit mode as in that's mode the browser doesn't :|  support Canvas Imagesmoothing

Comment: That is strange...Which Windows version are you on?  and what is the user-agent that is being sent?

Comment: Same problem on Win7 and 8..and also 10 but that's a virtual machine... What's user-agent?

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Comment: @colouredFunk I added screenshots of the openlayers url that you provided, working as expected in stagewebview on Windows 8 (IE11/Trident) and OS-X (Safari8/WebKit).

Comment: If you mean the "Null Island" stuff, Kind-of.. if you watch the DOM, some really weird updates (and delayed events) occur on the popup... But the 'same' strangeness occurs on Safari also but Safari acts on it different, especially the pointer changes. I'm assuming that is why ol.style.Icon is flagged as experimental in OverLayers and not in the stable list(?)... I not an openlayers guy...

Comment: hmm I wonder why is doesn't work for me!? Would you mind uploading your source code?

Comment: Out of interest what is your exact user-agent if visiting http://whatsmyuseragent.com

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko (that is from a Win8.1 VM using Air 19 beta (Quint))  And the source is really simple, just a new StageWebView(true); and setting the stage and viewport, nothing special.

Comment: OK so I'm really struggling with this now...I've just testing it on a Windows 8 machine with AIR 19 and using the following code, I can't click on the Marker displayed on the Map..

var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(true);
   webView.stage = this.stage;
   webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
   webView.loadURL("http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/icon.html");
@RobertN -Do you know why your setup might be different? Have you ever edited your registry for IE related matters?

Comment: The Win images I use for phy. & vms are provided to me so could they be different in someway, possible... security items are, etc.. (pm for details). Like I said, that vector icon does act funky and causes really delayed DOM changes, maybe the DOM/css changes for the pointer and activate events are not firing quickly enough, or in the right order? CPU speed issue? But it also acts strangely in Safari, maybe stay away from the experimental features and use a css based bitmap pointer instead? Air/Flash 19.0.0.188 just released today, any changes seen in that release maybe?

Comment: Stepping into 2017, I have a similar problem where I am trying to load google charts and it won't display on stagewebview with the native property set to true, but it will work just fine in IE11.